# Limit for animations query is not applied

Tags: angular, angular-animations

According to the [query](https://angular.io/api/animations/query) function documentation in the Angular animations package, you can supply an optional parameter `limit`. To my understanding, with `limit: 5`, only the first five elements that are found will be animated.

When I use `query` with `limit: 1`, only the first element is animated, but with any other number all elements will be animated.

See this [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/GcKQGou1Y6eoitms86ao/)

```js
transition(':enter', [
    query('p', [
      style({transform: 'translateY(-100px)', opacity: 0}),
      animate('1s', style('*'))
    ], {limit: 2})
  ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug and was fixed with this [PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/19258).
The provided plunker now works as expected.